# How to pass two parameters on the eventHandler of Material-UI Toggle?

Tags: reactjs, events, ecmascript-6, material-ui

In the documentation of Material-UI Toggle component it says:

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/toggle

```
onToggle - Callback function that is fired when the toggle switch is toggled.

Signature:
function(event: object, isInputChecked: bool) => void
event: Change event targeting the toggle.
isInputChecked: The new value of the toggle.
```

Now, in my code the component is as follows:

```
    <Toggle
      label="Advanced search"
      style={styles.toggle}
      onToggle={() => this.useAdvancedSearch()}
      toggled={this.state.useAdvanced}
    />
```

That would work, if the method would only need the event. Such as is the case with a normal HTML checkbox.

That doesn't work as the method needs the event AND the boolean as parameters.

How am I supposed to pass the event AND the isInputChecked boolean for the event handler method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply *extract* then in your event handler:

```
<Toggle
  label="Advanced search"
  style={styles.toggle}
  onToggle={(event, isInputChecked) => this.useAdvancedSearch(event, isInputChecked)}
  toggled={this.state.useAdvanced}
 />
```

Should you need only `isInputChecked` for example:

```
onToggle={(_, isInputChecked) => this.useAdvancedSearch(isInputChecked)}
```

Or as @trixn well pointed out:

`onToggle={this.useAdvancedSearch}`

and then handle the arguments in `useAdvancedSearch`

```
useAdvancedSearch(event, isInputChecked) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Or instead just change the definition of your instance method to `useAdvancedSearch(event, isInputChecked) {...}` and ignore the parameters you don't want to use. Then you can just pass it as the handler: `onToggle={this.useAdvancedSearch}` I don't see any benefits in inlining a function there because it has to be created on every  render.

Comment: @trixn nice one! :)

Comment: That's some JavaScript black magic right there ;) (Java dev here) thanks for that extra tip @trixn